# Font Awesome module is throwing error when Angular version updated

Tags: angular

I had updated my angular version from 7 to 10 by updating the package.json file and running npm install .

But post that i am getting this error in Font Awesome module -

[image] .

I tried re-installing font awesome module , but that didnt help .

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you updated Angular from 7 to 10, without migrating to 8 and 9 before? Angular suggests not to skip major releases

Comment: Yes migrated directly to 10 . do i need to migrate to 8 and 9 first ?

Comment: Yes, it is recommended. Please check https://update.angular.io/?v=7.0-10.0 `Warning: We do not recommend moving across multiple major versions.`